# undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass link.user.email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my `index.html.erb` file, I am getting an undefined method for email. I went into the rails console and tried running User.first.email and it worked perfectly. I tried taking out email and running `link.user` and that also worked. I am not sure why email is coming across as undefined when there is a user tied to a link and a user has an email. I am looking for some suggestions as to what may be going wrong.

Index.html.erb

```
<%= link.user.email %>
```

Schema with migrations already run

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
```

Models:

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    validates :user, presence: true
    acts_as_votable
    attr_accessor :avatar
    mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :links
    acts_as_voter
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Link Controller:

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @links = Link.all
  end

  def show
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @link = Link.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @link = Link.new(link_params)

    if @link.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

    private
    def link_params
      params.require(:link).permit(:title, :url, :avatar, :user_id)
    end
end
```

Error Message:

```
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendered links/_form.html.erb (2.7ms)
  Rendered links/new.html.erb within layouts/application (3.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 505ms (Views: 143.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass link.user.email
```

You are getting this error because `link.user` is `nil` for some links and hence it calls `nil.email` and fails with the mentioned error message.

You can use [try](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) to get rid of this issue like this:

```
<%= link.user.try(:email) %>
```

That way your program will not crash even if `link.user` is `nil` for some cases.

Comment: I do have one question, why do you think it is that email is coming across as Nil if there is a user and the user is signed in? I'm having trouble seeing how that could be Nil

Comment: According to the error message, `link.user` returns `nil` in some cases, which means there are some links that are not associated with any user. So, `link.user` is `nil` for those links. For that case, if you try: `link.user.email` then it translates to: `nil.email` and that's why you got the error message:  `undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Now I just need to figure out why my association between link and user aren't working? I have my link class with the association that it belongs to a user and a user has many links. Not entirely sure why it wouldn't be picking up the foreign key.

Comment: Wouldn't the `try` on `user` assume that `user` exists? IE it wouldn't achieve what the OP wants?

Comment: @Jbur43 if you don't have any validation for for Link object to always have an associated user, then its possible that you somehow created a link but did not associate any user to it. But, you can add a validation for the presence of the associated User in your Link model as shown in Rich Peck's answer below. That will prevent creation of any Link without a User. But, that won't fix any previous data that you already have in the database. So, you have to fix your already existing Link objects without user by associating a user manually to them.

Comment: @RichPeck Yes, try on user assume that user exists. But, the OP was having trouble with link as mentioned in the question. So, my answer fixed his issue and prevented his `index` page from crashing.

Answer (score 2):

I know you accepted another answer but I think it's incorrect.

---

The error means that you don't have the associative `user` object for your `link`.

If you're *expecting* each `link` to have an associated `user`, you'll be better using a [`validation`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence) to ensure it's presence on `create` or `update`:

```
#app/models/link.rb
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   validates :user, presence: true
end
```

This will mean that every time you create a `link`, it *has* to have a `User` object; preventing the error in the first place.

--

If that's how you need your application to run (IE only users can post links or whatever), you won't need the `.nil?` or `.try()` conditional statements in your view.

In short, I think the accepted answer is like painting over rust (no offense etc).

Comment: I think, it's incorrect that you said, `Accepted answer is incorrect`. He accepted that answer because it prevented his program from being crashed. Its definitely better to add the validation and prevent such error in the first place, but imagine the OP may already have Link objects in the database which he may not be able to reset, in that cae he still needs that `try` approach to prevent his `index` page from crashing.

Comment: It could be just one or few links that does not have the associated user, in that case the OP can manually update them in the database which I mentioned in comment above. Hope it clarifies the fact. Let me know if you still think my answer was incorrect :)

Comment: Hey Rich, I tried adding the validation, and now I can't submit a new link because the user is not there, which is a good thing because now I know that the association is still not working. I'm curious, do you or @KMRakibulIslam see why the association wouldn't be working in this case? I'm still stumped. I posted my new model.

Comment: I also posted my rails log. It is showing in the transaction that it see's my user_id, but then rolls back the transaction?

Comment: @Jbur43 I think you should create another question with the latest information.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of this error is `link.user` is `nil`. You have to check if it is `nil` like:

```
<% if !link.user.nil? %>
  <%= link.user.email %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be some `email` is `nil` for that particular `user` you can use `try` to escape from the `undefined method for NilClass`

```
<%= link.try(:user).try(:email) %>
```

it saves you if `user` is nil for that `link` also

or

```
<%= link.user.try(:email) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check Link Migrate file

```
class CreateLinks < ActiveRecord::Migration
```

In this file you need `t.belongs_to :user_id`